# Batch Apex updating 300,000 records and returning errors in CSV and sending as Email

Tags: apex, email, batch, heapsizelimit

I have to update 300,000 records using Apex Batch. I also have to send an email to the user with the CSV file containing errors from update operation.Assuming all 300,000 records give failure, if I use a map to save the error records and send email in finish method, I will get Apex heap limit exception.I am using Database.Stateful to keep track of all errors. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, you'll reach governor limits. Perhaps you should just store the errors in a custom object, then send an email to the importer with a link to a report or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting if anyone encounters the same problem, I felt there are 2 solutions.
First is to make it stateless and send email in execute method itself. 
Second is to chunk the batch of records in calling function before sending to Apex Batch class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom object like logBatchErrors  (fields-->batchName, errorRecordId, errorMessage ) and store the error records.
In the Finish method query records and send an email.

Query records like [select id, batchName, errorRecordId from logBatchErrors where createdDate > "batchstartdateTime"  and batchname = '--batchName---' ]