# Batch and Heap Size Limit to send all the information via csv to a specific emails

Tags: apex, batch, heapsizelimit

I am facing the same problem mentioned here ([Batch Apex updating 300,000 records and returning errors in CSV and sending as Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239482/batch-apex-updating-300-000-records-and-returning-errors-in-csv-and-sending-as-e)), we need to delete 300000 records and send the CSV when the batch is finished, I keep the information in a variable and kept the values of every run of the batch, but in some moments I get problems with Salesforce limit and heap size. I was thinking of a solution similar to what Anup Kage proposed, saving the records in an object and when the batch is finished, processing the data but I'm not sure if that is the best solution or if anyone find a better solution.

Comment: Holding the errors as custom object records is fair. It may however fundamentally be impossible to send all errors in the email. You can only query up to 50000 records in a given transaction so at most 50000 errors could be queried to include in the email. Worse, you are limited in heap space (12Mb in async) so you probably cannot construct the error email even if you have queried all the records. I recommend only emailing the first say 100 errors but include a link to a page that will list all the errors (basically a list view of your custom error object).

Answer (score 2):

Holding the errors as custom object records is a fair approach.

It may, however, be fundamentally impossible to send all errors in the email. You can only query up to 50000 records in a given transaction so at most 50000 errors could be queried to include in the email. If more than 1 in 6 of your records cannot be deleted for some reason you will exceed this limit.

Worse, you are limited in heap space (12Mb in async) so you probably cannot construct the error email for a high volume of errors, even if you have queried all the records.

I recommend only emailing the first, say, 100 errors but include a link to a page that will list all the errors (basically a list view of your custom error object).

It doesn't really matter which batch execution generated which errors either since, I assume, you would need someone to simply go through the failures and resolve them.

You can, of course, order by created date of the custom error object records, to get some idea as to which batch originated which. Alternatively you could store the batch job ID in the errors and the email, and incorporate this in a filter based on a URL parameter embedded in the email.